# Distinguish real building pictures from rendered ones

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification

I need to train an algorithm to identify rendered building images from real pictures. Here's an example:

A rendered picture
[image]

A real picture

[image]

The real pictures will vary from Good quality to Poor quality, (Like the one above) and will have many different aspect ratios. The same goes for the rendered pictures.

So what would you suggest me to use to do that, does anyone knows something that already do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

To apply machine learning, you need to find thousands of labeled examples of both real and rendered images.

After you have labeled data, most likely a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) will learn the differences between the labels.